# Value of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{99}\frac{n}{1+n^2+n^4}$

Tags: real-numbers

Please help me out with this problem.
 $$\frac{1}{(1+1^2+1^4)} + \frac{2}{(1+2^2+2^4)} + \cdots+ \frac{99}{(1+99^2+99^4)}$$
lies between

$(A)$ $0.46$ and $0.47$.

$(B)$ $0.52$ and $1.0$.

$(C)$ $0.48$ and $0.49$.

$(D)$ $0.49$ and $0.50$.

Explain the procedure

Comment: How to get the answer manually?

Answer (score 3):

By using partial fractions you get

\begin{align*}
\frac{k}{1+k^2+k^4}&=\frac{\frac12}{k^2-k+1}-\frac{\frac12}{k^2+k+1}\\[4pt]
&=\frac12\left[\frac{1}{\left(k-\frac12\right)^2+\frac34}-\frac{1}{\left(k+\frac12\right)^2+\frac34}\right]
\end{align*}
then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{99}\frac{k}{1+k^2+k^4}&=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{99}\left[\frac{1}{\left(k-\frac12\right)^2+\frac34}-\frac{1}{\left(k+\frac12\right)^2+\frac34}\right]
\end{align*}
observe that the last sum is telescopic, so
$$\sum_{k=1}^{99}\frac{k}{1+k^2+k^4}=\frac12\left[\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac12\right)^2+\frac34}-\frac{1}{\left(99+\frac12\right)^2+\frac34}\right]=\frac{4950}{9901}\approx 0.4999495$$

Hence the answer is $\color{blue}{D)}$.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider the fact that:

$$\frac{x}{1+x^2+x^4}=\frac{x}{(1+2x^2+x^4)-x^2}=\frac{x}{(x^2+1)^2-x^2}=\frac{x}{(x^2+x+1)(x^2+1-x)}$$

Then, considering the last one, you have:

$$\frac{x}{(x^2+x+1)(x^2+1-x)}=\frac{1/2}{x^2-x+1}-\frac{1/2}{x^2+x+1}$$

From where you can finish using a telescopic sum.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is D.

We can write it as $\frac{r}{1+r^2+r^4}$. So now we can write it as
$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{1-r+r^2}-\frac{1}{1+r+r^2})$ 
And after putting the values from 1 to 99 we will got 0.4999449